# How to select the last item of a nested unordered list

Tags: jquery

I want to know and understand how I can select the last item from a list which has nested lists.

Example

```
<ul id="first">
  <li>Look:</li>
  <li>This is some text in a list.</li>
  <li>This is a note about it.</li>
  <li>THIS IS WHAT I WANT</li>
  <ul id="second">
    <li>2nd This is another note about it.</li>
  </ul>
</ul>
```

For this example I want to have "THIS IS WHAT I WANT".

Play around with .last() only return the last (2nd This is another note about it).
I also tried this

```
$( "#first li" ).not('ul#second').last();
```

but it won't work too

Comment: Your selector says get all of lis inside of first. Make sure the the li is not ul#second. You want `$( "#first> li" )`

Comment: Your markup is invalid. All list content must be in a list item element. So you'll need to fix that, then reformulate your question. I'm not sure what it'll end up being.

Comment: @epascarello that is exactly what i was looking for! Thanks a lot, only the " >" was missing....

Comment: As @isherwood said - your markup is invalid - a ul can not be a direct child of a ul - it needs to be in an li - making this not a simple as last >li

Comment: If you're going with the `>` approach, this would be simpler: `$('#second').prev('li')`

Comment: `$('li').not('ul')` will always be true.  A `<li>` element is never a `<ul>` element.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's say you correct your markup to this:

```
<ul id="first">
  <li>Look:</li>
  <li>This is some text in a list.</li>
  <li>This is a note about it.</li>
  <li>THIS IS WHAT I WANT</li>
  <li>
    <ul id="second">
      <li>2nd This is another note about it.</li>
    </ul>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Now you probably want to get the last list item that does not contain another list. You can do this:

```
$('#first > li:not(:has(ul))').last();
```

[Fiddle demo](https://jsfiddle.net/isherwood/x0jce24v/)

https://api.jquery.com/not-selector
https://api.jquery.com/has-selector
https://api.jquery.com/last